# pass cell content to variable, process it and then Return it into another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have written an excel macro for my company, which, after selecting a cell with a serial number, generates a date from this SN (the date is encoded in the SN) and then subtracts this date from another date in the same row to generate a product lifetime in months. It works very well as a subroutine with a command button as trigger (see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot 1]

Now I would like to use this macro as some kind of formula, so that it returns the result of the the conversion / calculation in a cell at the end of the row instead of a messagebox. I converted the subroutine into a function already, but it only returns "#VALUE". Can anyone help me?

Here is the code:

```
Sub Lifetime()

Dim c As String
Dim m As String
Dim y As String
Dim d1 As String
Dim d2 As String
Dim d1cd As Date
Dim d2cd As Date
Dim d3 As Integer

c = ActiveCell.Value

If Len(c) = 9 Then

    y = Mid(c, 2, 2)
    c = Left(c, 1)
    m = Asc(c) - 64

    d1 = "20" + y & "/" & m & "/01"
    d1d = CDate(d1)

    d2 = ActiveCell.Offset(, 5).Value
    d2d = CDate(d2)

    d3 = DateDiff("m", d1d, d2d)

    MsgBox ("Die Lifetime der Pumpe beträgt " & d3 & " Monate")

ElseIf Len(c) = 12 Then

    y = Mid(c, 3, 2)
    m = Left(c, 2)

    d1 = "20" + y & "/" & m & "/01"
    d1d = CDate(d1)

    d2 = ActiveCell.Offset(, 5).Value
    d2d = CDate(d2)

    d3 = DateDiff("m", d1d, d2d)

    MsgBox ("Die Lifetime der Pumpe beträgt " & d3 & " Monate")

Else

    MsgBox ("Ungültige Seriennummer")

End If
End Sub
```

PS: Sorry, perhaps I didn't make myself clear (I'm not a native speaker): I want to use this function like a formula ("=Lifetime(B2)" for example), so I can drag down the fill handle and it processes the other rows automatically, like this:

[Screenshot 2](http://abload.de/img/vba28msvf.png)

Comment: You should not have magic numbers like 12 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by editing your subroutine. No need for using a UDF in a formula. Just replace the `MsgBox` lines in the sub with the following:

```vb
ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = "Die Lifetime der Pumpe beträgt " & d3 & " Monate"
```

This should place the output in the first empty cell to the right of the active cell.

Answer (score 0):

A user from the german board "vba-forum.de" helped me rewriting the script and now it works. here is the code:

```
'Modul1
Option Explicit

Public Function Lifetime(SerialNr As Variant, DateRef As Variant) As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim strDate   As String
Dim strYear   As String
Dim strMonth  As String
Dim dtm       As Date
Dim dtmRef    As Date

strDate = Trim$(SerialNr)
dtmRef = CDate(DateRef)

If Len(strDate) = 9 Then

    strYear = Mid$(strDate, 2, 2)
    strMonth = CStr(Asc(strDate) - 64)
    dtm = DateSerial(CInt("20" & strYear), CInt(strMonth), 1)

    'MsgBox ("Die Lifetime der Pumpe beträgt " & d3 & " Monate")
    Lifetime = DateDiff("m", dtm, dtmRef)

    ElseIf Len(strDate) = 12 Then

    strYear = Mid$(strDate, 3, 2)
    strMonth = Left$(strDate, 2)

    dtm = DateSerial(CInt("20" & strYear), CInt(strMonth), 1)

    'MsgBox ("Die Lifetime der Pumpe beträgt " & d3 & " Monate")
    Lifetime = DateDiff("m", dtm, dtmRef)

Else
    'MsgBox ("Ungültige Seriennummer")
    Lifetime = CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrNA)
End If

Exit Function

ErrHandler:
Lifetime = CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrValue)

End Function
```